# COM functions spawn threads that do not disappear

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, com

I am working on a small application that is meant to call some (really diverse) functions which are sadly out of my control and designed in such a way that I have no clue when the proper user action is done. In particular some of these spawn a thread to do their work in, which ends up dying at some point in the future. So some are implemented sync, some are implemented asynchronous, and my code does not know which of those it will be.

The **only** purpose of my application is to launch these tasks and terminate upon completion. Since the purpose is automation, I anticipate it being called 100s of times from batchfiles in a matter of moments, so I do not wish the process to linger any longer than absolutely possible.

Since I have no signal I can wait for, `ExitThread()` on my primary thread seems to be the way to go, so that any threads spawned by the foreign code will end up killing the process when they terminate.

So now to get to my actual issue mentioned in the title. :) In order to get the proper interfaces for my jig, I need to mess around with some COM functions. `SHParseDisplayName`, `IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf` and a bunch of others. But long after I am done with these interfaces and have released them, these threads remain present. Even after I called `CoUninitialize()`.

When inspecting my process using Process Explorer, the majority of these threads seem to have `ntdll.dll@EtwTraceMessageVa` as the entry point, and are stuck in `ntdll.dll!ZwAlpcSendWaitReceivePort+0xa`. Obviously, randomly terminating threads using `TerminateThread` is not an option here.

How can I get COM to terminate those threads when I am done with using it? I am using W7 x64 to develop on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, and it was an obvious case of all the documentation being somewhere but not where you are looking, and a somewhat related subject has had a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/05/28/8555658.aspx) on this issue which brought me to the missing piece.

My app pops up an `IContextMenu` of a file (hence no `ShellExecute` in my code), and then allows one to invoke a command. However, some verbs like `properties` are the oddballs that my question was about: they spawn another thread and give no notification or obvious way to block it.

Using SHSetExplorerInstance as mentioned in the linked post fixed my problems. :)

Answer (score 4):

Those threads don’t belong to COM. They belong to the native Windows thread pool. They are designed to stick around so they can be reused if necessary. Assuming there are no pending asynchronous callbacks you should be able to shut down cleanly. The thread pool will take care of promptly destroying the threads.

Comment: Weird, didn't get a notification you replied. Either way, my 'main' thread is dead, the thread it intentionally spawned is dead, and yet I'm left with a dead process with a bunch of threads in it that I cannot influence. I do not see any traces of them getting destroyed, I am afraid.

Comment: You probably have a COM interface reference counting bug or something else that’s holding on to resources. Either way if you’re using the C Runtime it should terminate the process once your main thread returns from main or wWinMain (regardless of what other threads may be running). It does this by calling the exit function. If you’re not using the C Runtime then you can call the ExitProcess function to achieve the same end.

Comment: I know all that. Did you read the question? It says exactly why I can't depend on ExitProcess and want to switch to ExitThread() if possible.  -- Regarding the reference counting.. I stepped through the code, keeping an eye on when the troublesome threads get created, but the interfaces involved in the commands in question are released several lines later.

Comment: I’m sorry if I didn’t read your question carefully enough. I’m just trying to help. Anyway those threads are created by the native thread pool. Unless you create the pool yourself you have no way to shut it down directly.

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put in. I just re-read and realized I might have come over a bit rude, which wasn't my intention. :)